# Changing default Styles in a Word document in a separate sub using Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In a word document controlled by Excel I want to make a subtle change to the used default styles. This works using the following code, when a word document is already open:

```
Private Sub basic_syle()
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objSelection As Word.selection

    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.application")
    Set objSelection = objWord.selection

    adjust_obj_style
End Sub

Sub adjust_obj_style()
    ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1").ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = False
End Sub
```

However if I want to let Excel create the word document and adjust the style the style is not changed.

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSelection As Word.selection

Private Sub basic_syle()
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objSelection = objWord.selection

    objWord.Visible = True

    adjust_obj_style
End Sub
```

While I think it has to do with the activeDocument class I did not yet find a correct solution. Activating the document object was no solution.

[Styles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.styles)
[PageBreak documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraph.pagebreakbefore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine the sub:

```
Sub adjust_obj_style(doc as Object)
```

and then pass that document to the sub:

```
adjust_obj_style objDoc
```

and then use that variable instead of `ActiveDocument` like this:

```
doc.Styles("Heading 1").ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = False
```

Comment: Thanks braX, I would swear that I tried something similar already. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also, you dont need to `Dim` the variables outside of the sub unless you need them somewhere else for some reason.

Comment: In my case I add text to the word document using another sub. Therefore the variables are declared outside. This leads to fewer variables passing around. Thanks for poining out anyway.